# Delphi 7 - How to convert an Integer to a String

Tags: delphi, label, progress-bar

I need my Label to read the percentage of the progressbar. For example if the progressbar is at 13% i need my Label to display 13, if it is at 76% I need it to display 76.

```
Label1.Caption := ...
```

What do i do?

Comment: Whenever you set the progress bar position, set the label caption too.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TProgressBar.Position

Comment: Do you know mathmatic? `CurrentValue / MaxValue` calculates the *percentage* of `CurrentValue` related to `MaxValue`. BTW *percentage* is defined as `1/100` or one per hundred (=centage)

Comment: I dont care about the %. The problem is that the position property of the progressbar is integer and i dont know how to make a caption which reads letters to read numbers. I am not a developer, i dont know how to code, i study civil engineering and i just need it for a project which doesnt have to do anything with coding :)

Comment: Probably you want a function to transform number to string. Look at IntToStr etc. One more variant: `Label1.Caption:= Format('%d %%', [IntegerValue]);`

Comment: You should Google your question first and then if you cannot find an answer, ask at StackOverflow. However, if it comes down to knowing that there are different data types (e.g. integer and string), then you should probably read a general introduction to programming first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are simply asking how to convert an integer to a string. Use `IntToStr` for that. For instance,

```
Label1.Caption := IntToStr(ProgressBar1.Position);
```

This assumes that `MinValue` is `0` and `MaxValue` is `100`. Otherwise the calculation for the percentage would be:

```
Percent := MulDiv(
  ProgressBar1.Position - ProgressBar1.MinValue,
  100,
  ProgressBar1.MaxValue - ProgressBar1.MinValue
);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's excactly what i needed!

Comment: Is `MulDiv` really called for here?  Unnecessarily specific to windows, deprecated in the 64-bit world, and perhaps a bit contrived in a case where overflow is not likely going to be a serious concern.  Seems prematurely defensive and a bit of a dinosaur...

Comment: @J... How would you do this?

Comment: The same way, just using normal `*` and `/` operators instead of `MulDiv`.

Comment: @J... what about overflow and why use floating point arithmetic

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I mean `*` and `div` - this post was weeks ago.  Are you really going to have overflow here?  I mean, perhaps when 4G displays become common and having a billion pixels of resolution to span a progress bar with... sure, I suppose it might overflow.  But surely by then we'll all be compiling for 64-bit, right?  This code will naturally break when that happens anyway since it won't compile against a 64-bit target (or any other target other than win32, for that matter).  I just don't see the value in using `MulDiv` here given the drawbacks.

Comment: @J... Overflow would be common for a 32 bit integer when dealing with file sizes

Comment: I suppose we have different approaches for setting a progress bar's max value... I wouldn't think to do it based on file size....

Comment: @J... How would you handle progress for a file read then. Hard to see how file size would not be used.

Comment: There are a myriad of ways to reduce a variable.  Even if not, you can always just use an `Int64` as intermediate if you're really worried about overflow.  At least it is cross-platform and works when compiled for 64-bit.  In any case, the original question was rhetorical - if you want to use `MulDiv` I really don't care.  It's just worth noting its limitations when offering it as a solution to someone else's problem so that they may decide with full information whether or not to use it themselves.  This was my only purpose in bringing it up.

Comment: Or just use floating point and `Trunc` it... it's a progress bar, not a quantum field calculation.  There are only so many pixels it can resolve.

Comment: @J... My rule is that if integer arithmetic can be used, it should be used.

Comment: I think we're just about 99.9% finished with this discussion ;)